# Searching algorithmics: Parsing and processing a request OOP style

Tags: algorithm, oop, language-agnostic, search

Say you were to create a search engine that can accept a query statement under the form of a String. The statement can be used to retrieve different types of objects with a given set of characteristics and possibly linked to other objects. In plain english or pseudo-code using an OOP approach, how would you go about parsing and processing statements as follows to get the series of desired objects ?

- get fruit with colour green
- get variety of apples, pears from Andy
- get strawberry with colour "deep red" and origin not Spain
- get total of sales of melons between 2010-10-10 and 2010-12-30
- get last deliverydate of bananas from "Pete" and state not sold

Hope the question is clear. If not I'll be more than happy to reformulate.

P.S: This isn't homework ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is well suited to a document-oriented store such as Lucene. For example you can design a schema such as

Type
Variety
Color
Origin
DateSold
etc
  :

Then you can write a Lucene query such as Type:Fruit AND Color:Green. You can also build nested queries such as (Fruit:Straberry AND Color:Deep Red) AND NOT Origin:Spain.

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a Java library with portts available for most major languages. [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a full-fledged search server built using Lucene lib and easily integrable into your platform-of-choice because it has a RESTful API.

BTW Solr has something called faceting which lets the user filter results using each of the criteria above. So user types fruit into search box and then gets results back.

---

Type:
 - Fruit (109)
 - Nut (99)

Origin:
 - Spain(32)
 - France(39)

Color:
- Red (22)
- Deep Red(45)

---

Clicking on each of the facets filters the results with the intersection. So if you want a more user-friendly interaction model, faceting/filtering is much easier, than getting users to type extensive Lucene queries.

Update: You might still need to do some lexical parsing if you wish to let users type natural language queries and break it down, but given the tremendously difficult challenge, my suggestion would be to use the simple & powerful faceting approach. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're developing a mini language, since you're concerned with syntax and parsing.  So, check out the many tools used to generate lexers and parsers.  You can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: Indeed :) . I'd also be interested in knowing how a request can be dispatched once it's been decomposed.

Comment: James: That is strongly tied to whatever you're querying.

Comment: I see. I'm simply wondering if it's a good idea to have a method that decomposes a request String and dispatches subrequests to a series of methods which deal with a single Object type. Or expressed in another way, imagine you have a DAO class with create, read, update, delete method. And then say you want an additional method that returns a series of objects according to criteria that carry on the attributes (a date span or colour) or associations with other classes.

Comment: James:  It still depends on what you're querying.  Sometimes you can get away with a sort of "streamed" approach to parsing.  Other times, you've got to process it all ahead of time.  (Linq to Objects and Linq to SQL have this kind of difference.)

Comment: Ok and thanks for your feedback. Will have a good think about this one. If I find a good solution I'll post back with some concrete code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John.

a) Start with lexical analysis
b) Take statistics of searches and use them to index
c) Find relationships by analysing possibly related searches

This is just a wild guess though, never tried it before.